# Blender's bundled Pythonのバージョンを変更する方法

Tags: python, blender

## 質問

Blenderをインストールした際に入っているPythonのバージョンをpython3.9からPython 3.7.10に変更する方法を教えていただけないでしょうか。
ただし、Blenderのバージョンは2.93.3で変更しないようにお願い致します。

下記のように、blenderからpythonを呼び出したいと考えております。

```bash
blender --background --python hoge.py
```

(実際にはhoge.pyはこちらのリポジトリhttps://github.com/PKU-EPIC/GraspNeRF/blob/main/run_simgrasp.sh#L22　のscripts/sim_grasp.py　です。)

## 自分で試したこと

blenderは下記のようにセットアップしました。

```bash
wget https://mirror.clarkson.edu/blender/release/Blender2.93/blender-2.93.3-linux-x64.tar.xz
tar -C /usr/local -Jxf blender-2.93.3-linux-x64.tar.xz
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/blender-2.93.3-linux-x64
```

blenderをダウンロードした際に入っているpythonのディレクトリは下記の通りです。
/usr/local/blender-2.93.3-linux-x64/2.93/python/bin/python3.9
そこで下記のようにディレクトリを削除しました。

```bash
rm -r /usr/local/blender-2.93.3-linux-x64/2.93/python
```

削除した部分にpython3.7.10を下記のようにダウンロードして解凍しました。

```bash
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.10/Python-3.7.10.tar.xz
tar -Jxvf Python-3.7.10.tar.xz --no-same-owner
cd Python-3.7.10
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/blender-2.93.3-linux-x64/2.93/python --enable-optimizations --with-openssl=/usr/local/ssl
make
make install
```

これで`/usr/local/blender-2.93.3-linux-x64/2.93/python/bin/python3.7`が配置されます。
ここで下記を実行すると、以下のようなエラーメッセージが出ました。
実行したコード：

```bash
blender --background --python hoge.py
```

エラーメッセージ；

```bash
Blender 2.93.3 (hash 8b80d19f3641 built 2021-08-17 23:40:09)
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = '/usr/local/blender-2.93.3-linux-x64/2.93/python'
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = '/usr/local/blender-2.93.3-linux-x64/blender'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 0
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/opt/conda/bin/python'
  sys.base_prefix = '/usr/local/blender-2.93.3-linux-x64/2.93/python'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/usr/local/blender-2.93.3-linux-x64/2.93/python'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = '/opt/conda/bin/python'
  sys.prefix = '/usr/local/blender-2.93.3-linux-x64/2.93/python'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/usr/local/blender-2.93.3-linux-x64/2.93/python'
  sys.path = [
    '/usr/local/blender-2.93.3-linux-x64/2.93/python/lib/python39.zip',
    '/usr/local/blender-2.93.3-linux-x64/2.93/python/lib/python3.9',
    '/usr/local/blender-2.93.3-linux-x64/2.93/python/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
  ]
Internal error initializing Python!
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

sys.pathの項目を見ると、まだPython3.9を認識しているようです。
これをPython 3.7.10に変更するには、どのようにすればいいでしょうか。
(単純にpythonのbinファイルを置き換えるだけでは駄目そうでした。)
また、sys.executable = '/opt/conda/bin/python'はblenderの外で自分が普段使っているpython環境です(python3.7)

## 実行環境

```
ホストPC：Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Dockerコンテナ: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
blender: blender-2.93.3-linux-x64
```

以上、お手数ですが何卒宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: どんな理由があって内部 Pythonを置き換えたいのでしょう？
[XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2701/)では？ (ちなみに たぶん内部の Python置き換えは不可能なはず … Blender動かなくなるはず)

Comment: @oriri 様 コメントいただきどうもありがとうございます。內部Pythonを置き換えたい理由は、`pybullet==2.7.9`をpip installするためです。動作確認したいと思っているコードのリポジトリ(https://github.com/PKU-EPIC/GraspNeRF)に、`blender-2.93.3-linux-x64
`で`pybullet==2.7.9`をpip installするように指示があるのですがインストールができず、Python3.7の状態だとpip installできました。內部Python(v3.9)でpip intallすると`ERROR: Could not build wheels for pybullet, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects`のようなエラーメッセージが発生しインストールに失敗します。おっしゃる通り、XY問題の可能性が高いかもしれません。Python3.9でも`pybullet==2.7.9`をインストール可能な方法を探すべきかもしれません。

Comment: 探し回るのは大変なので「pybullet==2.7.9をpip installするように指示がある」などの URLは記すようにしてください。質問もこれらの情報をもとに書き加えるなどしたほうがよいかも。 / [pybullet 3.0.8](https://pypi.org/project/pybullet/3.0.8/#files) かそれ以降から pybullet-3.0.8-cp39-**cp39**- のような Python 3.9用のファイルが用意されてそうなので試してみると良いかも

Comment: @oriri 様 度々コメントいただきどうもありがとうございます。お陰様で無事に私がやりたい事を実現することが出来ました。blender內部のPythonにはpybulletが入らなかったのですが、Python3.9をblenderとは別に新規にダウンロードしたところ、`python3.9 -m pip install pybullet==2.7.9`が通るようになりました(python3.9-devの有無が原因?)。blender內部のpythonは、`--python-use-system-env`オプションでPYTHONPATHを指定するとblender外部のモジュールを使用できるので外からインストールした`pybullet==2.7.9`が使えてリポジトリのコードの動作確認が出来ました。　依存関係の言及は https://github.com/PKU-EPIC/GraspNeRF#dependency (<-blender2.93.3であること)と https://github.com/PKU-EPIC/GraspNeRF/blob/main/requirements.txt (<-PyBullet2.7.9であること)にありました。言葉足らずですみませんでした。  今回は初めに教えていただいた通りXY問題で、そこに気づけたので解決の糸口が見つかりました。大変助かりました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@oriri 様にコメントいただいた通り、Blender's bundled Python のバージョンを変更するのは厳しいようでした。
ただしBlender's bundled Python のバージョンは3.9のまま、外部のPython3.9をblenderとは別に新規にダウンロードしたところ、`python3.9 -m pip install pybullet==2.7.9`が通るようになり無事解決しましたので自己回答させていただきます。
blender內部のpythonは、--python-use-system-envオプションでPYTHONPATHを指定するとblender外部のモジュールを使用できるので外からインストールしたpybullet==2.7.9が使えてリポジトリのコードの動作確認が出来ました。